# Wordpress Custom Widget error?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php code for my wordpress blog for registering  custom widget which gets latest post from a category and shows them. But looks like it is causing an issue on one of my pages on which I'm using it.
I'm unable to find any syntax error. Does anyone else find something wrong with the piece of code?

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

// This is where you run the code and display the output
query_posts( 'category_name=press-release&posts_per_page=5' ); 

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="about-pg-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>
<div class="about-pg-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title();?></a></div>
<?php
 endwhile; 
echo $args['after_widget'];
}

// Widget Backend 
public function form( $instance ) {
if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
$title = $instance[ 'title' ];
}
else {
$title = __( 'New title', 'thm_widget_domain' );
}
// Widget admin form
?>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php 
}

// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
$instance = array();
$instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
return $instance;
}
} // Class thm_widget ends here

// Register and load the widget
function thm_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'thm_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'thm_load_widget' );
```

Comment: What is the issue it is causing?

Comment: @Anigel Not a clearly visible issue. I use a frontend composer plugin with this widget on a page. And to me it looks like there is an endless loop going on outputting 25000 lines of html

Comment: So I'm narrowing down the potential reason of that huge output by first looking into this custom widget I registered. I doubt the plugin is causing the issue. Also I do not have any errors, the page doesn't just load because of its size

Comment: Just did a quick test, removed this widget from the page and the error has gone away now. This code is faulty for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to construct custom queries, it is totally unpredictable, rather use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Also, never forget to reset a custom query with `wp_reset_postdata();` when using `WP_Query` or `pre_get_posts`.

Rewrite your widget with these recommendations, and if it still fails, please post the widget's full code. Your current code is incomplete, so I can't do any test

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following function:

`function register_widget( 'thm_widget' ) thm_widget` is the class and constructor of the function.

[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget) is an example of how this is implemented in Wordpress.